# AsyncHttpClient vs ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchttpclient

I use [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) to make asynchronous HTTP requests. I came across ExecutorCompletionService. From what I understand, I could achieve the same behavior with it and also end up having a clean way to put all the responses into an output queue depending how and when the responses are ready. However, I'm not sure if there are other **performance differences** that I need to consider. Thoughts on the same are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ExecutorCompletionService + synchronous http client will consume as many threads as number of concurrent requests are going out. AsyncHttpClient can handle much more concurrent requests with less threads.

Comment: Thank you @hoaz. AsyncHttpClient provides more concurrency, but does it also mean that with a very large number of requests there could be a potential risk of a lot of these outstanding requests causing higher memory consumption?

Comment: Yes, each thread consumes a lot of system resources, even when it is blocked waiting for response.